# Does Ubuntu have gparted included?

Tags: gparted

As the title suggests, I need a live distro that has gparted included to work on some hard drive partitions.

Answer (score 0):

This page is outdated but it says, you can use a Live CD for disk partitioning

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD#Reasons_for_Using_a_LiveCD_Session

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latest GParted version in the Official GParted Live CD/USB from [**this page**](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). ([direct iso download page.](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php))

From the site:

> ## Live CD/USB/PXE/HD
>
> GParted Live is a small bootable GNU/Linux distribution for x86 based computers. It enables you to use all the features of the latest
>   versions of the GParted application.
>
> GParted Live can be installed on CD, USB, PXE server, and Hard Disk
>   then run on an x86 machine.

Additional information:

> ## Accounts in GParted live
>
> GParted live is based on **Debian live**, and the default account is "user", with password "live". There is no root password, so if you
>   need root privileges, login as "user", then run "sudo" to get root
>   privileges.

In the Official GParted Site you can find additional useful information such as the additional boot parameters and the list of included packages which comes pre-installed in the live CD.

Good luck!